# In what way are different (trivial) representations equivalent

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

A representation of a group $G$ is said to be [trivial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_representation#:%7E:text=In%20the%20mathematical%20field%20of,the%20identity%20mapping%20of%20V.) (over some vector space V) if $1_G:G\to GL(V)$ maps every element to the identity element in $GL(V)$.

Furthermore two representations $\rho :G\to GL(V)$ and $\pi:G\to GL(W)$ are said to be equivalent if there exists an *isomorphism*  $\alpha: V\to W$ such that
$$\alpha \rho(g) \alpha^{-1}=\pi(g)$$
for every $g\in G$.

Now, I would like to understand three different kinds of 'trivial' representations namely

- $1^{(1)}_G: G\to GL(\mathbb{C})$ (which sends $\forall g$ to $1$)
- $1^{(n)}_G: G\to GL(\mathbb{C}^n)$ (which sends $\forall g$ to the identity matrix)
- $1^{(\infty)}_G: G\to GL(l^2)$  (which sends $\forall g$ to $\text{id}$ on $l^2$)

These three trivial representations are obviously not equivalent (since there is no isomorphism of vector spaces of different dimensions. I still think it would make sense to say that these representations *are* equivalent in some way.

Is there a notion that captures that these three representations are still (essentially) the same 'kind' of thing although they are not isomorphic in the standard sense?

all references are welcome.

Comment: I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2964582/473276) question is relevant - both the proposed notion of equivalence and the discussion about it. Representations are commonly thought of as "a vector space $V$ equipped with some special functions $\rho(g)$ for each $g \in G$" - it's then sort of clear that the "right" notion of iso/homomorphism would be "an iso/homomorphism of vector spaces which plays nicely with the special functions". I think the perspective is unfortunately obscured somewhat by the "homomorphism to $\mathrm{GL}(V)$" definition of "representation".